# MySql Jsp error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

This page is redirected from another page where users enter their info and press register. This code is supposed to save the info into the database and automatically redirect them to index.jsp. For some odd reason the info does get saved in to the database but I still get this error.

Here is the error and the code:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /savereg.jsp at line 19

16: Statement st=con.createStatement();
17: String sqlqueryCommand="insert into subscriber(name, street_address, city, state, zip, email, login, password) values('" + name + "','" + address + "','" + city + "','" + state + "','" + zip + "','" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pass + "')";
18: 
19: st.executeUpdate(sqlqueryCommand);
20: 
21: response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
22: %>
```

Comment: What's the exception?  Also, that approach to executing sql is prone to sql injection attacks

Comment: when i put a try catch block around st.executeUpdate(sqlqueryCommand), it updates and redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using using a try/catch block and maybe a logger. Your code is vulnerable to sql injections. Make sure you close your database connection after using it. try this code below:

```
Connection dbConnection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
String insertTableSQL = "insert into subscriber(name, street_address, city, state, zip, email, login, password) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try{

   dbConnection = getDBConnection();
   preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

   preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
   preparedStatement.setString(2, street_address);
   preparedStatement.setString(3, city);
   preparedStatement.setString(4, state);
   preparedStatement.setString(5, zip);
   preparedStatement.setString(6, email);
   preparedStatement.setString(7, login);
   preparedStatement.setString(8, password); 
   preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


} catch (Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();   
} finally {
   preparedStatement.close();
   dbConnection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JDBC statement parameters. NOT build your sql like that. You may got attached SQL injection OR your SQL will be invalid when value contains single quote or other special chars ( Your case may be this case: SQL invalid )

I really recommend you process INSERT in Java servlet, then process Redirect in Servlet code. Should not use any kind of code like this at JSP.